# How do I close my own question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question in Stack Overflow? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work)

Motives aside, I want to close some of my questions. Many of which have answers.

Could someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: You have more than 250 points; you should be see a 'close' option under your tags.  However, you should not need to close your question usually.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 15):

There's a close link under the tags, just click on that, assuming you have enough reputation points, then choose the "no longer relevant" reason.

You need 250 reputation points for that but you currently only have 240, so I'll vote this question up to give you the power :-)

However, keep in mind that, even though you may not find it useful any longer, others may. Consider leaving it there for posterity.

Comment: I don't see the "no longer relevant" reason. Was that removed?

Answer (score 9):

Why do you want to close them?  Just accept the answer and allow them to continue.

I've seen many questions here where the "accepted" answer is not the best.  If someone comes along and wants to offer you some better advice on something you've asked, you should allow it.  At the very least, so others can see it.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that other people can still see a closed question?

Answer (score 8):

One thing to remember here is the purpose of the `close` feature is **not** to indicate that the question is resolved, and it's **not** to protect your question from abuse.  We have accepted answers for the former and ♦-moderator locks for the latter.

Rather, the purpose of the `close` feature is to allow the community to shutdown questions it feels should never have been opened in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on not closing your own questions - by definition you are the person least able to judge the answers, otherwise you wouldn't be asking!
I would also be carefull about closing other questions - really only if they are way off topic or duplicates.

Comment: The "one true answer" thing has been hard for me on the questions I've asked so far (2). In both cases, I've got answers to my exact question as well as really good suggestions to avoid it altogether. I vote them up, but some of the late comers offer great advice.