# Is there an option to close your own questions regardless of reputation?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation

So let's say that I received an answer that like and accepted it. While I have read [How do I close my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question), I do not nearly have enough reputation points to do that. If such a feature doesn't exist can it be created? People like me should be able to do that if they want to.

Comment: I think you may be may be misunderstanding why questions are closed... Why do you want to close your question if you have an answer that you accepted?

Comment: Because I no longer want any answers.

Comment: What you want is not relevant. Stack Exchange is about content. If you are bothered so much by this, delete your account if you don't plan to ask more questions or ask to disassociate the question from your account. Problem solved.

Comment: How do I delete my account?

Comment: @GameCoder http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only questions that aren't a good fit for the site should be closed, it isn't the equivalent of saying "this question is solved" but rather "this question doesn't meet the quality standards of this site". Closed questions are always closed with a specific reason, such as "Unclear what you're asking", "Too broad" or "Primarily opinion-based".

See [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/307988)

Accepting an answer is the only way you have to show that *your* issue is solved.

Stack Exchange Q&A's are however not only for you but future readers so there is no reason to prevent further answers.

Comment: Oh okay. But why would someone put an answer to a question with an already accepted answer?

Comment: @GameCoder because maybe someone has a better answer, more relevant info, the answer has changed over time... many reasons.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't always the best answer @GameCoder. Sometimes, it's not even correct.

Comment: Because it adds something useful for future visitors? Don't be selfish and think of the hundreds of other people coming at your question.

Comment: Oh. ok. It was probably a bad feature request then.

Comment: @GameCoder a bad feature request yes, but only because it was based on a fundamental misunderstanding, no harm done

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can only close your question if it is a duplicate of another question. If not, you need the appropriate reputation to vote to close on any question.

The most interesting question is: why do you want to close it? You say because you don't want other answers any more. Isn't that just a little selfish? Someone is trying to help you and you just want them to go away? For what?

As long as your question is on-topic it should stay on the site. Think of the hundreds of other people coming at your question. They can be helped by a new and better answer. Why deny them that?

I think this all started with the idea that SE is your personal assistant where you can get your answer for no effort. It is not! We try to make the site a useful knowledge repository for everyone, including you.